# Where to call DestroyWindow() of an MFC dialog?

Tags: mfc, dialog, destructor, destroy, ondestroy

I'm curently working on dialogs in an MFC application and I'm – admittedly – quite new to MFC.

Let's say I have class `A` (derived from `CDialog`) that uses class `B` (also derived from `CDialog`). Thus, `A::OnInitDialog()` calls the `create(...)` method of `B`.

I saw now that the destructor of class B contains

```
if ( GetSafeHwnd() )
{
    DestroyWindow();
}
```

Is this okay? In my understanding it would be better to call `B`'s `DestroyWindow()`method in `A::OnDestroy()`. Is that right?

Thanks for your help!
Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you may have noticed as you've delved in to MFC is that it is a wrapper API and not strictly object-orientated.  Whereas we would *like* to use RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialisation), MFC does not create windows in its constructor.  It does it, as you rightly point out, through the `Create()` method.

Therefore it makes more sense to me, given the way MFC works, To destroy `B` when `A` is being destroy (`A::OnDestroy`), so I think you're going down the right path.